# Qt - raise window to current desktop/workspace on Linux DE

Tags: c++, linux, qt, desktop-application

**Preconditions:** My Qt program (MainWindow) works on *FIRST* Linux desktop, and I work on *SECOND*.

Program invokes such piece of code:

```
mainWindow->raise();
```

**What happens?** My Desktop Environment switches to the *FIRST* desktop and shows main window on my app.

**What I want to happen?** Main window of my app is moved to the current (*SECOND*) desktop and shows here.

Is it possible with Qt and how?

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30113311/in-qt-5-whats-the-right-way-to-show-multi-monitor-full-screen-qwidget-windows?answertab=active#tab-top)

Answer (score 0):

Qt not support full Linux DE/WM environment. Virtual desktop is like not real virtual desktop.

This is complex question. I'll try explain (bad english).

Desktops and workspaces on Linux X Window System: https://www.circuitousroot.com/artifice/programming/useful/fvwm/viewports/index.html

Qt use xcb: https://xcb.freedesktop.org/
Here we have xcb connection: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qx11info.html#connection
This is hard way without other libraries: xcb, ICCCM, EWMH only...
I have this issue for my application, but later. I have only dirty tests on pure C, and it works.

You can try use (or look how to implement, I watched here) KWindowSystem: https://api.kde.org/frameworks/kwindowsystem/html/classKWindowSystem.html (which not have KDE dependencies!!!) but this class not have all functionality for all EWMH commands.